# javascript function call issue

Tags: javascript

Inside the google maps infowindow object I have called the showHotel() function but it did not gets called. When I just write alerert('') is works but my own defined function did not work.

```
   function showHotel(){
       alert('Wapal po');
   }
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<a href="#" onclick="showHotel()">Show Tasweer</a>'
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should globally declare `showHotel`. If you add event listeners to a HTML string, the current scope is not respected. Your current code probably looks like:

```
window.onload = function(){  //Or any inner function
    function showHotel() ... //This declares a local method       
    ...
       content: '<a ... onclick="showHotel()">'
    ...
}
```

A method to leak the `showHotel` method to the global scope is by prefixing the method by `window.`:

```
window.showHotel = function(){...}
```